# Save a string for later use in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, save

I have a simple string that I would like to save for later use on an ASP.NET server. It is an authorization string for a web service. It mostly stays the same, but may expire every few months. It will be saved programmatically from a code-behind file. Is there a simple place I can save it?

Initial thoughts are:

1. File - seems reasonable
2. Database - we don't have one setup and it seems like a lot of overhead to hold a string
3. Session - this would be too short lived
4. Config file - Based on answer from MK_Dev this would require a web app restart. No go then.
5. Somewhere else that I don't know about, but would be perfect?

Comment: Is it read-only or does the application itself change the string?

Comment: @MikeChristensen - The application itself will periodically update the string

Comment: Since you need to change it every 30 days, I'd probably store it in a XML file.  You might even want to encrypt it, since it's an authorization string used to authenticate you on a remote site.

Comment: @mrtsherman - Yea, a file is your best bet.  Or the Windows registry; it's a bit un-DotNet-like but it's a perfectly reasonable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility is to create a custom registry key. Here is an article with some code examples: [Manipulating and Editing Registry with .NET](http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/Registry/Manipulating_and_Editing_Registry_with_NET_135.aspx).

Comment: I like that.  Nice idea.  Doesn't need to restart the app pool to change it, and it can be secured quite nicely.

Comment: Wouldn't giving the application access to the registry be a security problem?

Comment: @mrtsherman - No, you can secure the value in the registry.  It's no different than securing a connection string in the Registry.  Microsoft even hass step-by-step guidance for encrypting it and storing it in the registry.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649224.aspx   This is really a good option, and it's a proven, field-tested option as well, at least for connection strings.  Storing your authorization key should really be no different.

Comment: You can set registry permission for a certain key, so you'd essentially only allow read/write access to that key to your AppPool user.

Comment: I'm having security issues. Is there a registry key that DefaultAppPool user would have permission on by default? I tried Permissions -> Add User on Software/MyCustomDir, but DefaultAppPool user doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Those instructions are for .NET 1.1.  Try either Network Service or IUser_<machine name>/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind restarting the app when the value changes, then config file is the way to go. If you need it to be fully dynamic, you can add a config table to the database and update it when changes.

Comment: Restarting the server will be a no go. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Not restarting the server but the web app itself. You can do it in ISS, for example

Answer (score 0):

How about server side cache?

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the string remains static for the most part, I would store it in Cache with an expiration and/or dependency. If you go the dependency route, you can use a file or store the string in the database, and it will update automatically if and when it's changed.

See this article for details: [Caching Application Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: As an additional reference - this page discusses expiration and such: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about `System.Environment` variables?

```
    System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("mystring","asdf");
    System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mystring");
```